# TKinter: How to auto update app to next version for a non-python user?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an app using TKinter that interacts with a database. This app will be distributed to 20+ users as a standalone `.exe` file since they will not have Python installed. What is the best way to update the version of the app, other than blocking the current version and forcing the users to download the `.exe` file with the latest version? For eg. Google Play Store App.

Comment: Are you embedding database credentials? If so, you could expire them to force an upgrade and handle login errors with a popup to upgrade to the latest version. If not, you could include a 'supported version(s)' field in your database and have your app refuse to work when out of date.

Comment: No credentials. Is that an only option right now? I wanted to know if there was a seamless way of doing an update without any disruption like the Google Play Store apps.